# Regex expression to divide mathematical and logical expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a way of dividing an expression into parts with regex. I'm currently splitting everything by spaces but that's not the correct way of doing it. Here is an example expression:

```
var expression = "#X+ 23>=#Threshold && #X * 4 != 54 || #IgnoreCheck"
```

The result I'm looking for is a list of all the parts:

```
["#X", "+", "23", ">=", "#Threshold", "&&", "#X", "*", "4", "!=", "54", "||", "IgnoreCheck"]
```

The characters to take into account for spliting:

```
&& || != + = - * / ^ > < <= >=
```

Comment: I think you should give a few more information about the syntax of your expression - this is definitly not splitted by spaces.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Thanks for the tip. I already added the characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
var res = Regex.Split(expression, @"\s*(&&|\|\||<=|>=|!=|[-+=*/^><])\s*");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%28%26%26%7C%5C%7C%5C%7C%7C%3C%3D%7C%3E%3D%7C!%3D%7C%5B-%2B%3D*%2F%5E%3E%3C%5D%29%5Cs*&i=%23X%2B%2023%3E%3D%23Threshold%20%26%26%20%23X%20*%204%20!%3D%2054%20%7C%7C%20%23IgnoreCheck). The main idea is to use alternation (`|`) since some alternatives are multicharacter strings.

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `(&&|\|\||<=|>=|!=|[-+=*/^><])` - capturing group 1 (thus, when used with `Regex.Split`, these parts will be output into the resulting array) matching

  - `&&` - two ampersands
  - `|` - or
  - `\|\|` - 2 pipes
  - `|` - or
  - `<=` - a `<` and then `=`
  - `|` - or
  - `>=` - a `>` and then `=`
  - `|` - or
  - `!=` -  `!` followed with `=`
  - `|` - or
  - `[-+=*/^><]` - any 1 symbol from this set
- `\s*` -  0+ whitespace

[image]

Comment: which is the program name?

Comment: @Edulynch: [RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%28%26%26%7c%5c%7c%5c%7c%7c%3c%3d%7c%3e%3d%7c!%3d%7c%5b-%2b%3d*%2f%5e%3e%3c%5d%29%5cs*&i=%23X%2b+23%3e%3d%23Threshold+%26%26+%23X+*+4+!%3d+54+%7c%7c+%23IgnoreCheck)

Comment: Since `Regex.Split` may and often does output empty items, they can be filtered by appending `.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))`